# Como ler números inteiros com Scanner e tratar entradas inválidas

Tags: java

Tenho o seguinte programa, onde preciso ler um inteiro, printar ele para o `System.out`

Contudo no meu código, quero que quando o programa receba um valor inválido como uma String, eu reporte o erro para o usuário e ainda continue esperando receber um inteiro.

Aqui está o código que tenho hoje:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true){
            System.out.printf("Entre com um número inteiro qualquer: ");

            try{
                int inteiro = entrada.nextInt();
                System.out.printf("Eis a aberração: %d", inteiro);
            }

            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.printf("Você não digitou um número inteiro!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Gostaria que quando o usuário digitasse um não-inteiro, ele pudesse ter outra chance para digitar um número inteiro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não vai funcionar com o `nextInt()` porque ele só funciona se você já tiver entrado com uma linha de dados, como você está usando `System.in` você tem que fazer dessa forma:

```
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

while(true){
    System.out.printf("Entre com um número inteiro qualquer: ");
    String linha = entrada.nextLine(); // ler a linha (termina no enter)

    try{
        int inteiro = Integer.parseInt(linha); // (tenta converter pra int os dados inseridos)
        System.out.printf("Eis a aberração: %d\n", inteiro);
    }

    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.printf("Você não digitou um número inteiro!\n");
    }
}
```

#### Exemplo do `nextInt()`

```
String s = "Hello World! 123 ";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);

while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println("entrou");
    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Eis a aberração: " + scanner.nextInt());
    } else {
        scanner.next();
    }
}
scanner.close();
```

> 123